# websocket-rails / puma: "async response must have empty headers and body"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, puma

I'm using websocket_rails to provide an API for a JS client. Locally it works great, but the exact same setup in production will (seemingly randomly) decide to stop working.

My production.log yields `RuntimeError (eventmachine not initialized: evma_install_oneshot_timer)`

At first I thought this was the root issue, but my Puma error log yields this when restart the server and try again: `RuntimeError: async response must have empty headers and body`

I added some logging in the puma gem, and indeed, it's receiving rails session headers when doing `GET /websocket`

Sometimes there is no issue at all, and everything works fine for a few days, and then, not. And no matter what I do it just refuses to work again.

Thanks in advance. I've wasted days on this problem!

Puma config:

```
# Change to match your CPU core count
workers 1

# Min and Max threads per worker
threads 1, 6

app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"

# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env

# Set up socket location
bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"

# Logging
stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true

# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
activate_control_app

on_worker_boot do
  require "active_record"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{app_dir}/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
end
```

Comment: Have you read this https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/430

Comment: Yeah, placing eventmachine above websocket_rails in the Gemfile doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Are you sure you got it right? You need to place websocket_rails above eventmachine (you said opposite)

Comment: Can you post your puma config file?

Comment: @AvaelKross Yes sorry, that's what I meant.